# Setting a function to power series with the $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ a_{n} \ x^n $ method

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let's say I have this function below

$$f(x) =  \frac{(x-1)}{x^2+2}$$

How do I represent it as a power series ?
The only solution that I know is when using the geometric series :
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^k = \frac{1}{1-q}$ but this is not possible in our case .

I asked recently this question with a different function by mistake
$$f(x) =  \frac{(x-1)}{x^2+1}$$
This is actually simpler and can be done with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^k = \frac{1}{1-q}$

I tried to integrate the function ($f(x) =  \frac{(x-1)}{x^2+2}$)  and then differentiated it but I stopped the process when I started finding out some bad result .

I checked some documentation and most of these functions (that don't work with a geometric series) should  work using this method   $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ a_{n} \ . x^n $ . The problem here is I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Can you do $\sum\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ ??  (How to choose $q$ so that the one you know matches this...) Then, can you do $\sum\frac{1}{x^2+2}$ ??  Then $\sum\frac{x}{x^2+2}$.

Comment: @GEdgar  oh okey

Comment: If you get the three that I mentioned, then you should be able to get $\sum\frac{x-1}{x^2+2}$.

Comment: For the first one , q is $-x^2$ but the second is tricky with the 2

Comment: maybe use $\displaystyle \frac1{x^2+2} = \frac12 \frac1{1+x^2/2}$

Comment: Your two geometric series should start with $k=0$ instead of $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Via partial fraction decomposition and geometric series:
\begin{align}
\frac{x-1}{x^2+1} 
&= \frac{x-1}{(1+i x)(1-i x)} \\
&= \frac{(1-i)/2}{1+i x} - \frac{(1-i)/2}{1-i x} \\
&= \frac{1-i}{2} \sum_{n\ge 0} (-i x)^n - \frac{1-i}{2}\sum_{n\ge 0} (i x)^n \\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(1-i)i^n((-1)^n - 1)}{2} x^n 
\end{align}